# Spring-Data JPA e Auditoria com update por @Modifying

Tags: java, spring-data

É possível realizar auditoria em uma operação de update com o Spring-Data Auditing usando o update via anotações `@Query` e `@Modifying` ao invés de usar o método `save()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Query` e `@Modifying` não tem relação com Auditoria. Elas são anotações que informam o Spring Data quando um método é apenas uma consulta, ou quando esse método efetua modificações como insert ou update.

Para trabalhar com auditoria em Spring, utilize AspectJ para interceptar o que você deseja auditar. Com essa api, você pode usar anotações como `@Before`, `@After`, `@AfterReturning`, `@Around` para atender aquilo que você precisa. Mais informações de como fazer isso você encontra [aqui](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/) informações mais detalhadas podem ser encontradas na própria [referência do spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

Comment: Ok, eu só queria confirmar mesmo se tinha essa possibeilidade ou não. Obrigado pela resposta e pelos links.